# LeakCanary doesn't report leaks

Tags: android, leakcanary

I've started integration of the **LeakCanary** and it reported one leak that I fixed. However, through the memory dump, I see that I have multiple instances of my activity. But LeakCanary is silent. I even don't see memory dumping toasts.

Yes, I do register my activity for leak checking through the `RefWatcherWrapper`.

What might be the issue. How to investigate case?

Comment: are you sure that those activities would be leaking? If you have a normal call stack there also can be multiple instances of your activity (e.g. `launchMode="standard"`)

Comment: I was thinking that I should have one activity instance when I rotate device (I have only one activity in my app)

Comment: Please paste a path2gc excluding weakreferences of your leak. Also make sure you manually trigger the gc before pulling the dump.